# Drop tcpdump permissions

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

Even after changing the group and ownership of tcpdump to user mode, I still get the following error:

```
tcpdump -i eth0
tcpdump: eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)

ls -la /usr/sbin/tcpdump
-rwxr-x--- 1 user1 user1 830920 Apr 24 21:28 /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

I know it is not good to drop the permission of tcpdump from root  to user but for ease of use in my case, I would like to be able to use it from user level.

I took the hint from:
["tcpdump -w 1.pcap" works, but "tcpdump -C 100 -w 1.pcap" - permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050659/tcpdump-w-1-pcap-works-but-tcpdump-c-100-w-1-pcap-permission-denied)

and installed AppArmor as I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

And did:

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

Still I get the same error msg. If I  use "-Z" with the tcpdump command, I can drop the privileges and run tcpdump but not otherwise.
Is there a way out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`libpcap` (which `tcpdump` is based on) require admin privilege to set your interface into promiscuous mode. There is nothing you can do about it, the kernel won't let you/`tcpdump`/`libpcap` do that, period.

What you *can* do is use `tcpdump` without promiscuous mode, but that will severely limit its functionality: you will only see traffic directed explicitly to/from your machine, as opposed to *everything that's seen on the wire*, which is usually what you want to to (and is why using promisc mode is the default). In order to do that, use this `tcpdump` option:

```
   --no-promiscuous-mode
          Don't  put  the  interface into promiscuous mode.  Note that the
          interface might be in promiscuous mode for  some  other  reason;
          hence,  `-p'  cannot  be used as an abbreviation for `ether host
          {local-hw-addr} or ether broadcast'.
```

For more info on promiscuous mode:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode

I quote:

> Many operating systems require superuser privileges to enable
>   promiscuous mode.

In Linux, at the low level, this is done by setting the `IFF_PROMISC` flag on the netdevice via a `SIOCSIFFLAGS` ("set flag") `ioctl`. And as you can see here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html

... "Setting the active flag word is a  privileged  operation", and "using it requires an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability.  If this is not the case, EPERM will be returned."

So another direction may be to give your "userjoe" account the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` rights, but I would advice against this. Security wise it's not better, if not worst, than to be part of the sudo'ers and explictly `sudo` when you need to.

Comment: Correction to the last paragraph: the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability is set on a binary, not a user and is a lot better than running the binary as `root` as it will not have all the privileges `root` has.